# How to check if the ElasticSearch cluster is running out of capacity?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have ES(1.7.3) cluster with 18 nodes. We have the following settings for each node:

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=90G
indices.fielddata.cache.size=75%
```

so total available heap is: `90G x 18 = ~1620G`. The cluster is becoming very slow on both read and write(used to be v fast). We have all nodes with `heap used` > 80%. Is that a clear sign we are about to running out of capacity from the memory perspective?

Comment: Can you add some more detail around your cluster config and usage please? Things like how much data, how many indices&shards, have you enabled doc_values and how many/large queries you are running and are you using filters for those queries would help get a better understanding of your situation. Also, is there a specific reason you chose to go above 32gb of heap space instead of running multiple nodes per physical machine?

Comment: We have around 50~ indices, 1900~ shards and 1.8T total. What you suggest if we wanna run multiple nodes per machine(2 nodes with 30G each)? Would it really bring an improvement to the performance?

Comment: I should think so, yes. Give the [elastic recommendations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/heap-sizing.html) a read, the issue is explained there fairly well. How much overall memory do your machines have? Does the shard count you mention include replicas or are those just the primaries? Shards come with a cost and that count seems fairly high to me - what were your considerations when configuring sharding? Last but certainly not least, are you using doc values for your mappings? Especially in pre 2.x clusters 3 out of 5 times this is the issue with excessive heap.

Comment: Hi @Shengjie, any news on your progress in this? I am curious to hear how you are getting on with your cluster :)